# Deteministic publishing order from a bounded dataflow pipeline to pub/sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

Is there a way to publish messages from a bounded dataflow pipeline (batch mode) into PubSubIO.Write in a deterministic order, so that they are delivered in that order, at least approximately. E.g. using timestamp or natural/sorted ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to deterministically order data written into PubSubIO.Write. Even if messages were published into Pub/Sub in order, your subscribers would not receive them in order as Cloud Pub/Sub has no ordering guarantees. In general, it is good to avoid a dependency on order as much as you can with Pub/Sub, though there are some techniques to deal with it. I recommend reading the newly-published [Message Ordering doc](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/ordering).

Comment: In addition, PCollections do not currently have a notion of ordering. The Dataflow batch runner splits a PCollection into arbitrary bundles of elements for processing and may resize/split those bundles depending on the runtime behavior of the pipeline.

Comment: Also, when publishing messages to PubSub, keep in mind that bundles can also be retried or duplicated for redundancy or fault tolerance, meaning that side effects of your DoFn's can be executed multiple times - so the consumers of the data you write to PubSub need to be aware of potential duplicates. The typical way to deal with this is to put some sort of logical "id" in your messages, identical across multiple attempts to compute/publish it. If the consumer is Dataflow, there are APIs for deduplication when reading from PubSub.